# magento - price is different for cart and catalog

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, price, frontend

### Problem:

Some shown price in the catalog(right one) is different from the shown price in the cart(wrong, old price).

### Other information:

- I compared some - working and not - Products and I found no difference    (Dashboard and CSV.table).
- The Data Base contains about 300.000 Products
- I'm using Magento 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Check if you need to reindex the catalog prices from index management.

Also, there are a lot of instances that might affect the differences in product prices when it goes to the cart:

- you might need to check from admin menu `Promotions` > `Catalog Price Rules` if you have any rules that affect the pricing of the product when it goes to the cart.
- make sure that the product displays the selling price (i.e special price and regular price) on the product page and category pages.

There might be another answer but hopefully, that helps.